# Unity3D: Make texture from one pixel of RenderTexture

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, render-to-texture

I have a single texture which I have rendered from a camera. I want to take a number single pixel values from this texture and make new textures (1-by-1 pixel) which I want to then apply to some objects.

Is there a way of defining a texture whose `colorBuffer` is just a length 1 array from another `colorBuffer`? Is there perhaps a simple way of writing a shader that will do the same task efficiently? Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

`GetPixel()` and `SetPixel()` are what you are looking for:

```
Color pixel = yourTexture2D.GetPixel(x, z);
Texture2D newTexture = new Texture2D(1,1);
newTexture.SetPixel(0, 0, pixel);
newTexture.Apply();
```

Please note that `Texture2D.Apply()` is cpu expensive, but proportional to the size of the texture so you can probably get away with that.

Also note that you may have to adjust the coordinates `x` and `z` in relation to the size of `yourTexture2D`, like this:

```
int x = transform.position.x / size.x * yourTexture2D.width;
```

For more details on this adjustment, check the [documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Texture2D.GetPixel.html).

Comment: That's kind of how I have been doing it. The difficulty is that `GetPixel` is not a method of `RenderTexture`.

Comment: yeah, I feel like I should be able to not do that. It seems to be just the `ReadPixels` method but with more pixels than I need.

Comment: I just feel that I shouldn't have to read from the graphics card at all.

Comment: I'm pretty confident you won't find anything inside Unity API, but I hope you find a way, I'd be very interested.

Comment: My solution to my problem, which I admit was not really within the scope of what I was asking, was to treat the  `RenderTexture` as a texture atlas, and just scale the uv components on my target meshes. It's like there were lots of individual textures, but there is very little (none?) cpu overhead. Basically, I didn't need to be making new textures at all!